# How to add CSP for Django CKEditor

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I'm not using CDN or any link for CKEditor but I have PIP installed it using pip install django-ckeditor. I have added all necessary CSPs and CKEditor configurations in settings.py file but CKEditor is not working in html.
Please help me fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can add `'unsafe-inline'` to `style-src` and it will work for you. But it does not look safe
2. You can add all the hash that your browser shows you and set up CSP reports in Sentry to keep track of changes
3. You can stop using CSP for this page
4. We can stop using CKEditor since it has all inline styles

I will choose option 2 and will consider option number 4 in the future.

Help links

- https://content-security-policy.com/examples/allow-inline-style/
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/advanced/csp.html#impact-of-csp-on-editor-features

Comment: i think `'unsafe-inline'` is required for script-src also for ckeditor 4. but it is better to set it this way only for the views which render ckeditor. I couldn't find yet which script causes the CSP error without unsafe inline. I doubt they are using inline `onclick` like attributes

Answer (score 0):

Try
`<p> {{form.media}} {{form.as_p}} </p>`
`<p> {{form.media}} {{form.as_p|safe}} </p>`

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* it answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.